# How to generate a matrix group with two generators?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $\text{GL}(n,q)$ denote the group of all the invertible $n$ by $n$ matrices over finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. $\text{GL}(n,q)$ be generated by two elements for all $n>2$. See [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03081088908817916).

Now my first question is:

> Given two elements $A$, $B$ in $\text{GL}(n,q)$, how to generate the
>   group $G=\langle A, B \rangle$ ? Can we find out all the maximal subgroups of $\text{GL}(n,q)$ ?

It seems this question may be to hard. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158120/subgroups-of-general-linear-group-with-two-generators). Thanks for provide any information about the first question.

Then the second question is:

> Let $n=2$, $q=5$.  Denote $${\displaystyle A={\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 \\
>  3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}}\in \text{GL}(n,q),  {\displaystyle
>  B={\begin{pmatrix}4 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}}\in \text{GL}(n,q).$$
>   Please compute all the elements in $\langle A, B \rangle$.

By the computation in magma software, $|\langle A, B \rangle|=|\langle A \rangle| \times |\langle B \rangle|$, where $|\langle A \rangle|=6$ and $|\langle B \rangle|=3$. It's special case.

So my third question is:

> Let $n=2$, $q=7$.  Denote $${\displaystyle C={\begin{pmatrix}6 & 6 \\
>  1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}}\in \text{GL}(n,q),  {\displaystyle
>  D={\begin{pmatrix}4 & 4 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}}}\in \text{GL}(n,q).$$
>   Please compute all the elements in $\langle C, D \rangle$.

In the third question, it has $|\langle C, D \rangle| \ne|\langle C \rangle| \times |\langle D \rangle|$. $|\langle C \rangle|=3$ and $|\langle D \rangle|=3$ while $|\langle C, D \rangle|=24$.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Your first question is actually two questions, the first one computational and the second one theoretical. As  you can see for yourself we can compute these thing in Magma or GAP provided that $n$ and $q$ are not too big. It is unclear what you are asking in Questions 2 and 3, since you seem to have done the calculations in Magma yourself, but for Question 2 the group $\langle A,B \rangle$ has order 24, not 18.

Comment: @DerekHolt I can compute these things in Magma by computer, but I don't know how it works. There is a function called "MatrixGroup" in magma. So Question 2 and 3 are asking how to implement function "MatrixGroup". How can I see that the group $\langle A, B \rangle$ has order 24 ?

Answer (score 5):

Magma uses an algorithm known as Schreier-Sims using orbits of matrices on vectors and $1$-dimensional subspaces, which is not really suitable for hand calculation.

Here is a way of calculating the order by hand, but I have to admit that it makes it a lot easier if you know the order of the subgroup and something about the subgroups of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$. Knowing that that this subgroup has order $24$, I expect it to be isomorphic to ${\rm SL}(2,3)$, so I can look for generators that satisfy a known presentation of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$.

We observe that $A^3=-I$, which is central. Also $A^2B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}3&0\\1&2\end{array}\right)$, and $(A^2B)^2 = -I$. So putting $x=A^2$ and $y=B$, $z=-I$, we see that $G=\langle A,B \rangle$ satisfies the relations of the group
$$\langle x,y,z \mid x^3=y^3=1, (xy)^2=z, zx=xz, zy=yz \rangle$$
which is a $2$-fold cover of $A_4$ and isomorphic to ${\rm SL}(2,3)$. Also, since $A^2B \ne \pm I$, $G$ cannot be a proper quotient of this group and hence $|G|=24$.

You can show similarly that $\langle C,D \rangle \cong {\rm SL}(2,3)$.